# BeautifulSoup find_all picks only first paragraph

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I thought that using find_all should give me all the paragraphs on the page. But the code below picks only the first one. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very obvious... I'll appreciate your help!

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_text(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    # delete unwanted tags:
    for s in soup(['figure', 'script', 'style', 'table']):
        s.decompose()

    # use separator to separate paragraphs and subtitles!
    article_soup = [s.get_text(separator=" ", strip=True) for s in soup.find_all( 'p', {'class': 'speakable'})]

    text = ' '.join(article_soup)
    print text

url = 'http://money.cnn.com/2017/06/22/news/paris-air-show-boeing-airbus/index.html'
get_text(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `article_soup` list has 2 items because that's the number of < p class="speakable" > tags on the page, so the `text` contains only the first 2 paragraphs.
If you want the full article you have to get all the < p > elements inside the < div id="storytext" > tag.
You can resolve this if you modify slightly the code in the `article_soup` comprehension :

```
article_soup = [ 
    s.get_text(separator=" ", strip=True) 
    for s in soup.find('div', {'id':'storytext'}).find_all('p')
]
```